# isomorphism of rings that arise in Iwasawa theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $p$ be an odd prime. Let $(1+p\mathbb{Z}_p)$ denote the multiplicative group of p-adic numbers 1 mod p. Why is
$$\mathbb{Z}_p[[(1+p\mathbb{Z}_p)]] \cong \mathbb{Z}_p[[t]] $$
(non-canonically) via $(1+p) \mapsto 1+t$?

This is claimed many places but I never see the details anywhere I read.

By definition we have inverse limit
$$\mathbb{Z}_p[[(1+p\mathbb{Z}_p)]] = \lim \mathbb{Z}_p[(1+p\mathbb{Z}_p)/(1+ p\mathbb{Z}_p)^n]$$
where on the right hand side we have the group algebra.  I'm struggling to understand for sure what elements of $(1+p\mathbb{Z}_p)/(1+ p\mathbb{Z}_p)^n$.

Comment: Do you know that (for $p \neq 2$), the multiplicative group $1+p\mathbb Z_p$ is isomorphic (via $p$-adic logarithm) to the additive group $p\mathbb Z_p$, which of course is isomorphic to the additive group $\mathbb Z_p$? In particular, the only interesting values for $n$ there are the powers of $p$.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Thanks, I didn't know that and so read up on the p-adic log and it's useful. So $ \mathbb{Z}_p[[1+p\mathbb{Z}_p]] \cong \lim_n \mathbb{Z}_p[\mathbb{Z}_p/p^n]$ and this last part seems easier but I still can't get its isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p[[t]]$

Comment: What is the group ring $\mathbb Z_p [C_{p^n}]$ for the cyclic group of order $p^n$? Can you relate it to a certain quotient of the polynomial ring $\mathbb Z_p[t]$?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg $\mathbb{Z}_p[\mathbb{Z}/p^n]\cong\mathbb{Z}_p[t]/(t^{p^n}-1)$, and as as $n\to \infty$ the inverse limit gives $\mathbb{Z}_p[[t]]$? I knew $\mathbb{Z}_p[[t]] = \lim \mathbb{Z}_p[t]/t^{p^n}$ but was having trouble identify the two

Comment: but I guess they are they same as $\mathbb{Z}_p$-modules and also as algebras

Comment: Almost there. Now the limit of the $(t^{p^n}-1)$- quotients does not (naturally) go to $\mathbb Z_p[[t]]$. But remember that if $\gamma$ is a generator of the cyclic group (and unravelling identifications so far, that is the image of $1+p$), the standard iso sends it to $(1+t)$. So let's look at the quotients $\mathbb Z_p[t]/((1+t)^{p^n}-1)$ instead. Now look at $n\to\infty$ and you should, with the help of $p$-adic thinking, be able to identify that with the standard limit you knew.